# Apache .htaccess give me a No input file specified

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I known I'm asking about a well known problem, but I'm not a pro with LAMP stack and the answers I found doesn't fit my issue. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule myservices/user/(.*)$ myservicesapi.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

which works pretty well on my Apache 2.4, but gives me back a "No input file specified" as I put it (together with `myservicesapi.php`) on my hosted web service. Previous version of my .htaccess was this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule myservices/(.*)$ myservicesapi.php/?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and it worked well on hosted web server too. How strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some good readings I was able to manage this issue. I completely rewrote my rules this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=(.*)&password=(.*)$
RewriteRule myservice/user/create(.*)$ myserviceapi.php/create?email=%1&password=%2 [QSA,R,L]
RewriteRule myservice/user/login(.*)$ myserviceapi.php/login?email=%1&password=%2 [QSA,R,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=(.*)$
RewriteRule myservice/user/balance(.*)$ myserviceapi.php/balance?email=%1 [QSA,R,L]
RewriteRule myservice/user/deposit(.*)$ myserviceapi.php/deposit?email=%1 [QSA,R,L]
RewriteRule myservice/user/logout(.*)$ myserviceapi.php/logout?email=%1 [QSA,R,L]
```

Now I can manage two parameters and rewrite the urls the way I want both on my localhost and customer's remote host.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the `QSA Flag` which states :

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

what `QSA` does it that it tells the server to process your example
`myservices/$id` to `myservicesapi.php/?id=$id`, if parameters not specified it would throw this error.

which means that apache waits parameters (Query string in your case `?id=$1`) to be set to process it if you don't wish to work with them anymore just remove the flag `QSA`.

Comment: Hello, I'll try removing the `QSA` flag but why on my local Apache `RewriteRule myservices/user/(.*)$ myservicesapi.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]` works well? Shouldn't give me the same error on both hosts?

Comment: I got server infos, it's not an Apache, it's a nginx. Ops.

Comment: lol but to be clear Apache>2.4 Fix some minor issues as the following automatically